# basic syntax for .sty file

Tags: errors, packages, compilation-error

I'm trying to make a .sty file with all the packages and things that I use often, but I'm getting an egregious number of errors. Most of them are to do with the specific packages I am using

(for instance: Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.) even though these packages cause no problems in my other documents,

but the one that I think is crucial is "Emergency stop. <*> main.sty *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)"

Here is the code:

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ upgreek }
.... %a whole bunch of packages
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
.... %a whole bunch of commands
\endinput
```

I've tried various random things such as removing \endinput and putting \begin{document} \end{document} at the end, and adding a \documentclass{article} at the top, but I don't really know what I'm doing and none of them have worked.

I am using overleaf, if that makes a difference.

Comment: that (most likely) means that you are running latex on `main.sty` instead of running it on a document that does `\usepackage{main}` (and has `\end{document}` which that error is telling you is missing)

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error (most likely) means that you are running latex on `main.sty` instead of running it on a document that includes the package via

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{main}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

The error is basically saying that it reached the end of the input without seeing `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the ... from your sty, then it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mypackages.sty}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ upgreek }
%.... %a whole bunch of packages
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
%.... %a whole bunch of commands
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mypackages}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: what you say is true but I suspect it doesn't answer the actual question, the ... % bunch of packages were an attempt t shorten the example for this website not literally the code in the package file.